# Wpf Decimals Styling

Tags: wpf

I want to Style a TextBox with decimal places like this:

[image]

How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you want it editable?

Comment: Preferable yes.

Comment: You could do it with a RichTextEdit but it'd be a real hassle (forget binding), and the formatting would get garbled when the user edited it. You could ungarble it on focusout or whatever but it'll be ugly. How badly do you need the feature? Readonly is a snap: Just bind two Runs in a TextBox, with converters to spit out partial strings of the different parts of the decimal value.

Comment: mmm I was trying with custom control and Binding but it was a Nightmare. For now Just need a style when not editing-

Comment: Does it have to be a TextBox? It would be such a waste to spend time on getting a TextBox to do this while it isn't a good match. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem I do think it can be done by writing a ControlTemplate that contains two textboxes and a lot of key handling code.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd ControlTemplate could be a good approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the `TextBox` like this.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

public class DecimalTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FloatColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FloatColor", typeof(Color), typeof(DecimalTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Colors.Red));
    public Color FloatColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(FloatColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FloatColorProperty, value); }
    }

    protected TextBlock _textBlock;
    protected FrameworkElement _textBoxView;

    public DecimalTextBox()
    {
        _textBlock = new TextBlock() { Margin = new Thickness(1, 0, 0, 0) };
        Loaded += ExTextBox_Loaded;
    }

    private void ExTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= ExTextBox_Loaded;

        // hide the original drawing visuals, by setting opacity on their parent
        var visual = this.GetChildOfType<DrawingVisual>();
        _textBoxView = (FrameworkElement)visual.Parent;
        _textBoxView.Opacity = 0;

        // add textblock to do the text drawing for us
        var grid = this.GetChildOfType<Grid>();
        if (grid.Children.Count >= 2)
            grid.Children.Insert(1, _textBlock);
        else
            grid.Children.Add(_textBlock); 
    }

    protected override void OnLostKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostKeyboardFocus(e);

        _textBoxView.Opacity = 0;
        _textBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    protected override void OnGotKeyboardFocus(KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotKeyboardFocus(e);

        _textBoxView.Opacity = 1;
        _textBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);

        // making sure text on TextBlock is updated as per TextBox
        var dotPos = Text.IndexOf('.');
        var textPart1 = dotPos == -1 ? Text : Text.Substring(0, dotPos + 1);
        var textPart2 = (dotPos == -1 || dotPos >= (Text.Length-1)) ? null : Text.Substring(dotPos + 1);

        _textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
        _textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run {
            Text = textPart1,
            FontFamily = FontFamily,
            FontSize = FontSize,
            Foreground = Foreground });

        if (textPart2 != null)
            _textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run {
                Text = textPart2,
                FontFamily = FontFamily,
                TextDecorations = System.Windows.TextDecorations.Underline,
                BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.TextTop,
                FontSize = FontSize * 5/6,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(FloatColor) });
    }
}

public static class HelperExtensions
{
    public static T GetChildOfType<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj == null) return null;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = (child as T) ?? GetChildOfType<T>(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**XAML code usage**

```
<local:DecimalTextBox FloatColor="Maroon" />
```

And your output should look like this:

[image: screenshot]

*Update 05/17*

Explanation: As you can see from the image, the `DecimalTextBox` displays the text in formatted mode only when its not focused.

I had initially developed the control to support formatting during edit (which can still be done by commenting the methods `OnLostKeyboardFocus`, and `OnGotKeyboardFocus`) - but because of the font-size difference the cursor positioning was getting slightly skewed, which in turn would translate to bad user experience.

[image: cursor issue]

Therefore, implemented the swap logic during `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` to fix that.

Comment: Hi I was trying to use this code but using's are missing, I have an ambiguous reference between  System.Drawing.Color and System.Windows.Media.Color, could you provide me the right using's ?

Comment: That is the exact thing I was looking for. Just a minor issue when it is included in DataGridTemplateColumn when the row is selected it doesn't take the default selected colors. But It is another question. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: This works great, and this answer should be accepted. The only thing @SharadaGururaj answer is missing is some explanation - that his control has two modes - one for editing, and one (shown on focus lost) for displaying formatted text.
The same can be done with switching templates (one for focused control, one for not).
Juan Pablo Gomez - if you can - don't do it with RichTextBox. It's always slow and hard to maintain.

Comment: @swiszcz I had assumed the attached image would convey that  :) - I will update my answer with the explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a TextBox, because TextBox only accepts color changes to the entire text. You should try with RichTextBox, that allows loop throug TextRange's. Look at [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tamir/2006/12/14/richtextbox-syntax-highlighting/) sample of syntax highlighting with a RichTextBox.

I actually understood how it works and made it:

```
private void richTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox.TextChanged -= this.richTextBox_TextChanged;

            if (richTextBox.Document == null)
                return;

            TextRange documentRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
            documentRange.ClearAllProperties();

            int dotIndex = documentRange.Text.IndexOf(".");
            if(dotIndex == -1)
            {
                richTextBox.TextChanged += this.richTextBox_TextChanged;
                return;
            }
            TextPointer dotStart = GetPoint(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, dotIndex);
            TextPointer dotEnd = dotStart.GetPositionAtOffset(1, LogicalDirection.Forward);

            TextRange initRange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, dotStart);

            TextRange endRange = new TextRange(dotEnd, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);

            endRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));

            richTextBox.TextChanged += this.richTextBox_TextChanged;

        }
```

Suscribe the textbox TextChanged event to this method. You can now set the styles you want to every part of the text like this:

To change the last part (after the dot char) `endRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));`

To change the first part (before the dot char) is the same but for the initRange variable. If you want to change the 'dot' style, then create a new TextRange with `dotStart` and `dotEnd` TextPointers and apply styles to it. You can do other things like change font style, size, etc.

This code result looks like this:
[image]

All this is just for style. For checking that is a number is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a custom control with this main properties:

- `FloatNumber`: the original number, that should be a `DependencyProperty` to be Bind from the control.
- `NumberOfDecimalDigits`: a number to choose how many decimal digits to represent, that should be a `DependencyProperty` to be Bind from the control.
- `FirstPart`: a string that will contain the first part of the decimal number
- `Decimals`: a string that will contain the decimal digits of `FloatNumber`

Of course this is just a scratch, those properties could be implemented better to extract `FloatNumber` parts.

```
public partial class DecimalDisplayControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DecimalDisplayControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        (Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NumberOfDecimalDigitsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "NumberOfDecimalDigits", typeof(string),
            typeof(DecimalDisplayControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnFloatNumberChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FloatNumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "FloatNumber", typeof(string),
            typeof(DecimalDisplayControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), OnFloatNumberChanged));

    private static void OnFloatNumberChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as DecimalDisplayControl).OnFloatNumberChanged();
    }

    protected void OnFloatNumberChanged()
    {
        int numberOfDecimalDigits = Convert.ToInt32(NumberOfDecimalDigits);

        float fullNumber = Convert.ToSingle(FloatNumber);
        float firstPart = (float)Math.Truncate(fullNumber);
        float fullDecimalPart = fullNumber - firstPart;
        int desideredDecimalPart = (int)(fullDecimalPart * Math.Pow(10, numberOfDecimalDigits));

        FirstPart = $"{firstPart}.";
        Decimals = desideredDecimalPart.ToString();
    }

    public string FloatNumber
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(FloatNumberProperty);
        set { SetValue(FloatNumberProperty, value); }
    }

    public string NumberOfDecimalDigits
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(NumberOfDecimalDigitsProperty);
        set { SetValue(NumberOfDecimalDigitsProperty, value);  }
    }

    private string _firstPart;
    public string FirstPart
    {
        get => _firstPart;
        set
        {
            if (_firstPart == value)
                return;

            _firstPart = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _decimals;
    public string Decimals
    {
        get => _decimals;
        set
        {
            if (_decimals == value)
                return;

            _decimals = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Its XAML:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="WpfApp1.CustomControls.DecimalDisplayControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Orientation="Horizontal">

        <TextBlock
                FontSize="20"
                Foreground="Black"
                Text="{Binding FirstPart}" />
        <TextBlock
                FontSize="10"
                Foreground="Red"
                Text="{Binding Decimals}"
                TextDecorations="Underline" />

    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

Then you can use it in your page and bind a property to make it change dynamically:

```
<Grid>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">

        <customControls:DecimalDisplayControl
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            NumberOfDecimalDigits="2"
            FloatNumber="{Binding MyNumber}" />

        <TextBox
            Width="200"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding MyNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

The final result:

[image: The final result]

Comment: Not directly, you can edit it from the binded property-